# Call procedure inside trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to update counter table when user table is modofied.

I have created a trigger where i will cal this procedure.
But this procudeure is not creating.
Please tell me what error in this procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE barproc(IN id int,IN val int)
BEGIN
DECLARE @total_products int;

set @total_products=(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user where a=id and status='active')

if(@total_products>0)
    update counter
    set b=val
    WHERE a = id and status='active';

END if;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE barproc(IN id INT, IN val INT)
BEGIN
IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM `user` 
     WHERE a = id AND `status` = 'active') THEN
    UPDATE counter
       SET b = val
     WHERE a = id AND `status` = 'active';
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```